# Best way to send data to a remote device in Android

Tags: android, networking, udp, wireless, datagram

My question is, which is the best way to send data to other device in the same network?

I have two devices, both connected at the same wireless, both of them have a service which is the responsible of Network discovery and all this stuff.

Once device "A" know where is the device "B" this create a datagram socket. Then when you touch the screen of the device A, it sends to devices B, using datagram packets, some data. But this data must be in real time.

Now I'm getting around 200ms of delay, between the screen is touched and the device B received the packet.

So, I want to know if there is some other way to decrease this time and make it more faster.
I choose UDP because is more faster and it doesn't care if there are lost on the way.
But maybe there are better ways to do this.

Thank you!

**Device A send to B code**

```
@Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try {
                    if (clientSocket==null || clientSocket.isClosed() || !clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                    }
                    EngelPacket p = new EngelPacket(0,1,0,1,0);
                    p.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    byte[] sendData = p.getPacketBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                            sendData.length, ipDest, port);
                    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: 200ms looks like a acceptable delay for network based communication on Android. Are the 2 devices high end devices ?

Comment: @KiranKumar what you mean on high end devices? 
On is a tablet and the other is a special device. But both are working with android 4.1 and the hardware is quite good.
It depens on the network, but now is working better, don't know why